# What is yum - q and what's its purpose?

Tags: package-management, yum

Please tell me what is `yum -q` about? and what's its utilize?
I now the other option of yum but I don't understand `yum -q`!

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked out `man yum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to run yum without output.  It's typically used with -y

Answer (score 4):

From the `man yum` output (`man` *is what is what you should probably check out in the first place for any command before asking it there*):

> -q, --quiet
>       Run without output. Note that you likely also want to use -y.

So in essence this option prevents `yum` from outputting anything to standard file descriptors (STDOUT, STDERR). In practice that means you won't see any output in console.

`man` also references `-y` option:

> -y, --assumeyes
>       Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
>       Configuration Option: assumeyes

So `-y` option automatically answers *yes* to any console prompt that `yum` makes.

Together `yum -qy` would allow you to run `yum` without any output and manual confirmation which makes it quite handy for automation scripts.